# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in

Tags: php, html

estou com um erro nesse trecho... não sei o que pode ser

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comentarios where ativo='sim' order by id DESC");
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql )){
    $data_2 = $linha['data'];
    $hora_2 = $linha['hora'];
    $nome = $linha['nome'];
    $comentario = $linha['comentario'];

    $data_2 = implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$data_2)));
?>
<font class="data"><?php echo $data_2 ?> - <?php echo $hora_2 ?></font>
<p class="texto_comentario"><?php echo $comentario ?></p>
<p class="nome_comentario">Autor: <?php echo $nome ?></p>
<p style="border-top:#F7F7F7 1px dotted;"></p>
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você não encerrou a o bloco que código do comando WHILE.
Está faltando uma chave (ou chaveta, brace, curly bracket) em seu código `}`.

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comentarios where ativo='sim' order by id DESC");
    while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql )){
        $data_2 = $linha['data'];
        $hora_2 = $linha['hora'];
        $nome = $linha['nome'];
        $comentario = $linha['comentario'];

        $data_2 = implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$data_2)));
    } //faltou este
?>
<font class="data"><?php echo $data_2 ?> - <?php echo $hora_2 ?></font>
<p class="texto_comentario"><?php echo $comentario ?></p>
<p class="nome_comentario">Autor: <?php echo $nome ?></p>
<p style="border-top:#F7F7F7 1px dotted;"></p>
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Faltou fechar uma chave 
Troca a ultima linha por

```
<?php } ?>
```